# how can i fetch a texel from a multisampled texture beyond the number of samples it has

Tags: opengl, textures, multisampling

Suppose I created a multisampled texture with 8 samples.

And my fragment shader is

```
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2DMS tex;
in vec2 txcoords;

void main()
{
    vec4 col;
    ivec2 txSize = ivec2(textureSize(tex)* txcoords);
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        col += texelFetch(tex, txSize, i); 
    color = col/8;
}
```

This works fine.
However if I replace the for loop above with

```
    for(int i=10050;i<10058;i++)
```

this still works. (By works, I mean i still get the right image)

Why? Shouldnt OpenGL have generated a invalid operation error.

Similarly, even though the texture has 8 samples, I can still fetch 9th sample, if i = 9? Doesnt sound right to me. The Fragment shader should have failed at run time.

Comment: Where exactly would you like OpenGL to generate an invalid operation? Shaders aren't evaluated like other API functions; the best you could hope for is GLSL compiler static analysis to detect that you're using samples out of range, and that will likely never happen. And it probably did "fail" at runtime, its just that the behavior in this case is undefined so anything that happens after that is technically correct :P

Comment: Atleast if not an invalid operation error, I expect the color output to be garbage or all zeros (0,0,0,0) when i >= 8 in this case. Or atleast when i >= GL_MAX_SAMPLES.

Comment: Yeah, you should not expect these sorts of things. You'll be burned more often than not when it comes time to port software - undefined behavior usually only makes itself known when a different implementation behaves differently.

Comment: "*I can still fetch 9th sample, if i = 9?*" No, that would be the *tenth*. Zero-based indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should point out that ordinarily buffer accesses that are out-of-range have undefined behavior in OpenGL. However, with the recent push in OpenGL 4.x for improved robustness, there is an extension that will allow you to define the behavior in these cases.

`GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior`

This extension works by passing a new flag to your OpenGL context when you create it, and then buffer accesses that are out of range will result in well-defined values.

In your case, a `texelFetch (...)` that is out of range will return `vec4 (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`